# how to use openocd jtag burning FUSE_USER

Tags: openocd, jtag

how to use openocd jtag burning FUSE_USER

I want to write a tcl file
use jtag commands irscan and drscan
I failed
I don`t known why
Is there any other way
and openocd is support or not
thank you very much

Body must be at least 220 characters; you entered 150.